# Minimum steps to reach target, given (1, 0) and operations A = 2A - B or B = 2B - A

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I had an interview and I was not able to give a best approach for the problem.

```
A=1, B=0
- Operation L: A=2A-B
- Operation R: B=2B-A

For each step, only one operation(L or R) is taken place.

For a given number N, what is the minimum number of operations required to make A or B equals to N?
```

The most important one is an efficiency.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In k operations you can get all values of N in [-(2^k)+1, 2^k].

Notice that abs(A) + abs(B) = 2^k for all possible k paths, and that A & B exactly cover the range [-(2^k)+1, 2^k] in the set of paths of length k.

```
k=0: (1,0)
k=1: (1,-1), (2,0)
k=2: (1,-3), (2,-2), (3,-1), (4,0)
etc...
```

Given N we can find the minimum k via log. Then we know the final pair is (N, N - 2^k) (or (N-2^k, N) if N <= 0). It's easy to follow the path back up to k=0 because one of the two elements will be out of range for the next smaller k.

E.g., N = 35.

```
Log2(35) = 5.13, so we use k=6.
2^6 = 64, so our final pair is (35, -29)
(35,-29) -> (3,-29) -> (3, -13) -> (3, -5) -> (3,-1) -> (1,-1) -> (1,0)
```

Figuring out k is O(1), finding the path is O(k) which is O(log(abs(N)).

It's not likely you need to prove anything in an interview, but if you did, you could use this:

By observation: A - B = 2^k for k steps observed for small k.

Then via induction: we have some valid (A, B) s.t. A-B = 2^k. Then L gets us (2A-B, B), but 2A-B-B = 2A-2B = 2(A-B) = 2^(k+1) as desired. Similarly for R.

Comment: *"Notice that abs(A) + abs(B) = 2^k for all possible k paths"* - this seems like a very unsuitable interview question, if the solution is to pull this rabbit out of a hat.

Comment: @kaya3 I'm guessing the interviewer would be satisfied with the candidate noticing that everything between -(2^k)+1, 2^k is reachable in k steps and accepting that without proof.

Comment: @kaya3 There does seem to be a [simple logical assessment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66614354/2034787) we can make that doesn't require sampling steps, although I wouldn't think it easy in an interview setting.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a challenging task for an interview but I would start with the recursion of trying to find the origin from the result. Given valid `(A', B)`, where `A'` is the target we are after,

```
A' = 2A - B
```

for some `A`, which means that

```
A = (A' + B) / 2
```

The latter tells us that all `(A' + B)` in the path must be divisible by 2, and since the path ends (starts) at 1, all the `(A' + B)` in it are powers of 2.

Another property we can observe, although it may not be relevant to the solution is that once we switch in the first step to `(even, even)` or `(odd, odd)`, we cannot switch back.